# GetAttachmentCollection for more than 1 ID?

Tags: list, spservices, attachments

I need to get URL's and names of attachments from List and I found such code in `SPServices` documentation. I wonder if there is a way to do the same operation for more than one `ID` and get separate `Div` or `li` elements for each `ID`:

```
    $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetAttachmentCollection",
    listName: "MahAwesomeListName",
    ID: id,
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        //console.log( Status );
        //console.log( xData.responseText );

        var output = "";

        //debugger;
        $(xData.responseXML).find("Attachments > Attachment").each(function(i, el) {
            var $node = $(this),
                filePath = $node.text(),
                arrString = filePath.split("/"),
                fileName = arrString[arrString.length - 1];
            output += "<a href='" + filePath + "' target='_blank'>" + fileName + "</a><br />";
        });
        $("#drop-zone").html(output);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use GetListItems. On the success method, use a loop and invoke the code you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which gets all items in a list and then gets attachments for each item.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "MahAwesomeListName",
    /*CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",*/
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        var output = "";
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("ows_ID");   
            $().SPServices({
                async: false,
                operation: "GetAttachmentCollection",
                listName: "MahAwesomeListName",
                ID: id,
                completefunc: function(xData, Status) {                         
                    $(xData.responseXML).find("Attachments > Attachment").each(function(i, el) {
                        var $node = $(this),
                            filePath = $node.text(),
                            arrString = filePath.split("/"),
                            fileName = arrString[arrString.length - 1];
                        output += "<a href='" + filePath + "' target='_blank'>" + fileName + "</a><br />";
                    });

                }
            });     
        });
        $("#drop-zone").html(output);
    }
  });
});
```